# Как получить ассемблерный листинг кода, созданного gcc?

Tags: gcc, ассемблер

Как получить ассемблерный листинг кода, созданного gcc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для этого есть опция -S.

```
$ cat z.c

int main() { return 0; }

$ gcc -S z.c && cat z.s

    .file   "z.c"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $0, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: В дополнение: если добавить ключ `-fverbose-asm` - ассемблер будет разбавлен комментариями, из которых будет гораздо легче понять, что происходит и для какого участка кода сгенерированы те или иные команды.

Comment: И ещё: по дефолту ассемблерный код выводится в AT&T синтаксисе, а чтобы переключить вывод на Intel синтаксис ассемблера, надо добавить ключ `-masm=intel`.